# Unable to clean project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

OS version: Ubuntu 14.04 LTE 64 Bit

Java JRE/JDK version: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_11

Project directory is on a NTFS based drive.

Whenever I try to clean my project I get something like below.

> :app:clean FAILED Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
>
> > Unable to delete file: /media/DriveA/AndroidStudioWorkspace/DNA/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/.../mechandising/MerchandizingActivity$3.class

When I try to delete the build folder manually I get the following error.

> Error when getting information for file
>   '/media/DriveA/AndroidStudioWorkspace/DNA/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed':
>   Input/output error

I am unable to figure out whether its a Linux problem or a Studio problem. I don't face such a problem in Eclipse (Same Drive) so I am just considering it to be something wrong with my studio.

Any Suggestions??

Comment: It's suggested [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/input-output-error-when-accessing-a-directory) that it's hardware problem. Check what your drive's SMART reports.

Comment: have you download latest version of sdk tool from sdk manager ?

Comment: @Haresh Yes! I have the latest SDK tools and the latest build of studio.

Comment: same problem here with the same configuration. I also have the project folder on a NTFS and even launch AS as root doesn't resolve the problem. Are you launching AS as root?

Comment: Disabling Instant Run solved this problem

Comment: Check out answer in a similar thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41913598/5950360

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You need to go to the source file directly. 
Close the studio and go to the path the issue is located at and delete the folder there.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what I've done when I had the issue. But closing the IDE 6 or 7 times a day is painful, especially when the project is quite heavy and long to reinit with Gradle and indexing. I would love to know what's causing this :( I first though that's when I change the device in the USB cable. But it's not the origin.

Comment: did anyone find the source for this. deleting the file doesn't work for me

Answer (score 21):

Go to

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck
>   this Check box (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Thanks 
Have a nice coding

Comment: This was the solution for the problem I was facing on my Windows machine. It seems that Android Studio when you change between branches in Git, blocks random .jar files and clean cannot be executed.

Comment: It does not help.

Comment: This is right answer . And after doing this close all java and xml file in android studio , and then Invalidate cache and restart , it should work.

Answer (score 14):

You can go into the project directory and call gradle from the command-line to do a clean on the project:

```
gradlew clean
```

When you reopen the project you will need to run a gradle sync again.

Comment: Can you also share other gradle commands (for build, rebuild etc)

Comment: That is probably outside the scope of this question (and my expertise), fortunately a quick google search for 'gradle command line' will answer your question.

Comment: Try this its Working.

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into the same issue now - I accidentally edited one of the generated files and wanted to rebuild the app, but both `clean` and `build` failed due to some files being locked.

Luckily, I got `cygwin` on my Windows machine, so `ls -l <file that studio complained about>` revealed that these files were owned by some `Administrator` dude.

My first thought was that these files might had been created while Studio was running with admin privileges (I do this when I need to fetch updates from `SDK manager`). The idea was to try and resolve this issue by executing `clean` in Studio running with admin privileges, and later rebuild with normal privileges. Nope, this did not work :(

I decided to go for the brute force: `sudo rm -rf app/build/*` (in `Cygwin` this command looks a bit different: `cygstart --action=runas rm -rf app/build/*`). This resolved the issue and I was able to rebuild the project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. I tried some of the solutions proposed on this page and it didn't work. So I used [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to find which process is locking the apk file and it was firefox. I think it keeps the file locked when I upload the apk in google play console. To make that go to "Find > Find Handle or DLL... > path-to-your-app.apk".
Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

On Linux this could happen if you have a **`locked`** directories that prevents Android Studio from Deleting files.

you can run the Following command on Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME
```

Then try to rebuild --> Works for me

Comment: In Linux, owning the project directory, as Gal Rom suggested, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped the windows defender it was locking the file because it was need to scan  , and the problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

Go to your projects directory in the terminal and run `gradlew clean`

To run a Gradle command in your terminal/command prompt. Navigate to the root of your project and type `gradlew` in the terminal or `gradlew.bat` for the command prompt (windows users), followed by the command you would like to execute.

For a list of all possible gradle commands type `gradlew tasks` into your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when I was trying to debug my first android app. If you are running Android Studio on windows, I just restarted the Android studio and I did run Android Studio as Administrator which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by closing android studio -> remove android platform via cli and then -> add the android platform again -> open project in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on Windows, but OS X.  Somehow my build folder didn't have the proper permission for AS to delete the file so I did `chmod -R 777 <your_directory>` in the affected parent directory.. probably 777 isn't what you would want but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gal's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904628/2870404).

In windows, using Windows file explorer,

1. right-click on the directory,
2. click properties on the context menu that will appear,
3. then uncheck the "Read Only" attribute.
4. After that, click the "Apply" to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem.

Thanks to Gal's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904628/2870404).

In windows, using Windows file explorer,

right-click on the directory,
click properties on the context menu that will appear,
then uncheck the "Read Only" attribute.
After that, click the "Apply" to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
To build the project again and again I had to delete the build folder each time. The problem for me was an anonymous program called **ByteFence.exe** running in my system. When I uninstalled that program my issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

none of above answers didn't work for me, but change permistion works:

```
chown user:staff ../project_dir
find ../project_dir -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ../project_dir -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a process lock the file handle. You can try to open your task manager to kill the process. In my case, the process is one of the Java process hold by Android Studio OpenJDK. Just find it and kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread because I was having issues with my /release/app.aab getting locked. This prevented me from completing a project clean and generating a signed bundle. My work around was to restart my computer to get permissions back until I solved the issue.

It turns out that Git was locking the app.aab, and all I had to do was add "/release" to my /app/.gitignore.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go To File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck this Check box (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code).

2) Restart your android studio

Answer (score 0):

Running android studio as **administrator** in windows worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) **first run cordova clean cammand**

> ionic cordova clean

2)**After that run build command**

> ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by Upgrading  gradle version in build.gradle(project)