# How to project clean in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-cleanup

I am new in Android Studio so I face some problem with it. I am looking for a way how to project clean.

In Eclipse I would do `Project -> Clean -> OK` but I don't know how it is done with Android Studio.

Comment: In android studio option is given in build menu Clean Project
Build - > Clean Project

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can clean your project doing this

`Build > Clean Project`  or `Build > Rebuild Project`

Also you can do the `gradlew clean`

[image]

As @Kellogs commented :

Manually delete the `[project]/.gradle` as `hidden folder` as that one is the main culprit for large cleaned projects sizes.

Comment: and don't forget to manually delete the [project]/.gradle hidden folder as that one is the main culprit for large cleaned projects sizes.

Comment: @kellogs Added an edit, if you think it needs more explination feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 22):

> Cleaning an android project is quite simple just follow these steps

```
1. Click on Gradle pane,found in the top-right corner of Android Studio 
2. Click on your project,then Tasks -> build ->clean
```

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Note** Never clean your project using the Build -> Clean Project.Instead of cleaning your project it will increase the size of it.

**Update** `clean` has been replaced by `cleanBuildCache` in the recent versions of Android Studio.