# Boot_complete broadcast not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a boot_completed broadcast in my app, but it isn't working. The app is not installed on the SD card.

Android manfest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Bootreceiver.java

```
package nl.bicknos.TWPD;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
 public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gestart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} }
```

I've search and the solutions I found there didn't work

Comment: Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: I have that already in my manifest.xml

Comment: Are you getting a crash or the BroadcastReceiver is not invoked while phone is booted?

Comment: @Bicknos Did you check my edit on my answer? it solved your problem? You have to mark any question as a correct :)

Comment: I've checked your edit, but my testing phone wasn't sending the intent because it was running beta firmware

Comment: @Bicknos well... just mark any answer as a correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problemen, it wasn't the code, but my phone. There wasn't a single app that started een my device booted. Since i was running a beta version, I downgraded and now is it werking.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if you have implemented in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Your `intent-filter` should be

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 </intent-filter>
```

On your broadcast you have to add

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Gestart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Note : I guess your mistake was trying to pas `this` when you've got no `context`.

### EDIT

Also you can try to make a `Log.d` instead of `Toast` put :

```
Log.d("Restarted", "I'm on BR");
```

If your `BroadcastReceiver` is not calling then try to replace your `manifest` receiver to this :

```
<receiver android:name="nl.bicknos.TWPD.BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

It's obvious but maybe there's the error... your `<uses-permission>` needs to be a child of the  element...

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I've checked it and everything is like you said, but it isn't working. I think that the broadcast receiver isn't invoked.

Comment: If you are on AndroidStudio do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28581254/4385913) otherwise Clear your project

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in

`Toast.makeText(this, "Gestart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
 `this` here does not belong to any UI Activity. Your receiver is actually getting called. But as you are "Toast"ing not in the UI context, you are not able to see the Toast message. if you try to add a log in this onReceive() , you will see it coming in the "logcat".

I hope this helps :)