# Android Studio - multiple errors when building APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, apk

When I try to build a signed Android Package (".apk") in Android Studio, it says:

```
Error:(14, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/Midgar-Flower-Girl').
```

I also get this error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/gregoryopera/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is my manifest (release/AndroidManifest.xml), as shown in Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gregoryopera.wmwatch.midgarflowergirl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/Midgar-Flower-Girl" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="watchmaker.watch"
            android:value="1" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What is the issue, and how can I correct this issue?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:(14, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/Midgar-Flower-Girl').

It means that `Android Studio` doesn't find the `@string/Midgar-Flower-Girl` in your `res/values/strings.xml` folder.

> and how can I correct this issue?

Make sure that in your `res/values/strings.xml` do you have a `string` named `Midgar-Flower-Girl`, if you do, maybe the best solution is make a [code cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581254/4385913)

Comment: By mistake, I had put the name of my application in the android:label="@string/app_name" > field of AndroidManifest.xml, instead of in the <string name="app_name">Midgar Flower Girl</string> field of strings.xml!

When I read your post, I wondered whether this was what I had done and when I went looking, sure enough, you were right!

Thanks.

Comment: @GregoryOpera You are welcome I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in one of your resources files as you are referring to a string `Midgar-Flower-Girl` by `@string/Midgar-Flower-Girl` but it doesn't exist. Check again your strings file.