# Rendering Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio.And I came accross this problem under activity_main.xml tab  . So, How to fix this.I have installed the android studio 1.4.1 bundle offline. Also I can't drag and drop widgets to phone in activity_main.xml.But I can drag and drop in content_main.xml

```
 Rendering Problems
 The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE 

Exception Details  

 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.  
 at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)  
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)   
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)  
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) 
  Copy stack to clipboard
```

Here is my activity_main.xml in text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your activity_main.xml?

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s Hey I had posted .Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, its theme most be from AppCompat. To fix this issue, correct the following:

1. Open the file *app/res/values/styles.xml*
2. Change the following lines in the *styles.xml* file to look like this:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

`<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />`

and

`<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`.

They all need to inherit from **AppCompat** for your chosen layout. See the default working *styles.xml* file below. You can copy and paste it into your *styles.xml* file.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

3. If you are still having issues, go to the *app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml* file and make sure that  the value for the theme looks like this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` or this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` this way they are inheriting from the AppCompat themes as listed above.

See here as well: [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: styles.xml is same as you said. I mean its exactly what you said. And I still got the error under activity_main.xml

Comment: Clean the project if you can, then, try the solution in the link at the bottom of my post.

Comment: See here for how to clean: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28581211/3337765 if this doesn't work you'll have to paste more code. There is a simple solution to this problem I promise.

Comment: @SubashAryal please let us know what you did to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

The parent of `AppTheme` need is child or `Theme.AppCompat` . Pls check style: `@style/AppTheme` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` inside the `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and tried many things but what worked for me was simply updating the Android Studio version from 3.1.1 to 3.2 and it solved the exact same issues. Hope this helps.