# Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library

Tags: android, android-studio

> Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use
>   a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:184)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

**My acivity_main.xml is :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

my styles.xml is

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: This may be issue with the style selected please [see this..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959478/rendering-issue-in-android-studio)

Comment: i have tried its not working .. @EmdadHossain

Comment: hello all the prblem is fixed now..                                                                              change your style parent to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" instead of "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"                                                     it worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

Logcat output is clear, Set your `AppTheme` to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat>
</style>
```

You can find this in values file and you can also check manifest file to see what theme your are imposing.

Comment: Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Comment: try this `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: tried <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">