# com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView not displaying any content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to make a bottom Nav using android studio, but it will not display. if I add height to it, I can see the BG color but still no content of the menu items

EDIT:
its treating the menu xml as empty.

here is my code, ive also tried changing the layout to linear, frame and constraint:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".HomeScreen">



    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/btnSignUp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my menu item, its located in a menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="Home"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_receipt_black_24dp"
        android:title="Orders"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Account"
        />

</menu>
```

and lastly my dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:1.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity works? I miss the code for onCreate()!

Please add an id for the BottomNavigationView e.g.:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

In your Activity must be code like this. Is it there?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener( mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
             // ... implement code here
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

Edit: are the icons (e.g. ic_home_black_24dp, see picture) in the drawable folder and shown in Android Studio when displaying menu.xml?
[image]

Comment: i've tried it but it still wont display anything. i think its treating the menu xml as empty

Comment: are the icons (e.g. ic_home_black_24dp) in the drawable folder and shown in Android Studio when displaying menu.xml?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer here:

[Rendering Issue in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959478/rendering-issue-in-android-studio)

seems it was a rendering issue with the theme and had to change to appcompat.

thank you