# Difference between clean, gradlew clean

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

What is the difference between the following statements when issued from a Android Studio Project's terminal :

> Android_Studio_Project_Path: ./gradlew clean
>
> Android_Studio_Project_Path: ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
>
> Android_Studio_Project_Path: ./gradlew clean :assembleDebug
>
> and normal Android Studio --> Build --> Clean.

What would be the difference in the internal process.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

1. `./gradlew clean`

   Uses your project's [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) to execute your project's `clean` task.  Usually, this just means the deletion of the build directory.
2. `./gradlew clean assembleDebug`

   Again, uses your project's gradle wrapper to execute the `clean` and `assembleDebug` tasks, respectively.  So, it will clean first, then execute `assembleDebug`, after any non-up-to-date dependent tasks.
3. `./gradlew clean :assembleDebug`

   Is essentially the same as #2.  The colon represents the task path.  Task paths are essential in [gradle multi-project's](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), not so much in this context.  It means run the root project's assembleDebug task.  Here, the root project is the only project.
4. `Android Studio --> Build --> Clean`

   Is essentially the same as `./gradlew clean`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio).

For more info, I suggest taking the time to read through the Android docs, especially [this one](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html).

Comment: Glad I could be of help.  Gradle is awesome, especially for managing complex builds such as Android.  I'm looking forward to many other features for native builds coming soon...

Comment: What about shortcut: **Shift+CMD+C**?  Why doesn't that delete the build directory?

Comment: Can you provide a link to that shortcut's description? I couldn't find it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html), unless I missed it.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but these commands only remove project/build folder, but project/app/build stays untouch. Can anyone advice how to remove build folders in sub-modules too. Thanks in advance

Comment: @aruy Not a stupid question. `gradlew clean` should run the `clean` task for the _current project_ directory and any _subprojects_. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#executing_tasks_in_multi_project_builds). 2 questions you must ask. Is project/app a _subproject_ of the project's build that you are running? Is the project/app/build folder really a build output directory?

Comment: greate but what exaclty differecen sorry I mean whta is purpose of assmbleDebug/

Comment: @NicollasMatheus this is the _default_ definition of the `assembleDebug` task - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode

Comment: Fyi, the OP was trying to understand the different invocations of the gradle command line. Not what the tasks accomplish. 

Please note that these tasks can change over different versions of the Android plugin and/or different projects, etc. So, be careful not to assume too much about what each task specifically does. However, unless the build author is really mean, it should achieve the same end result.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use

`./gradlew clean build` (Mac and Linux) -With ./

`gradlew clean build` (Windows) -Without ./

it removes build folder, as well configure your modules and then build your project.

i use it before release any new app on playstore.

Comment: @ichimaru If you use the Powershell terminal, the command must be as follows: `.\gradlew clean build`

Answer (score 13):

You should use this one too:

`./gradlew :app:dependencies`             (Mac and Linux)   -**With** **./**

`gradlew :app:dependencies`              (Windows)    -**Without** **./**

The libs you are using internally using any other versions of google play service.If yes then remove or update those libs.