# React Native compilation for Android fails on Windows due to 'build' folder issue

Tags: android, intellij-idea, react-native, compiler-errors, directory

Sometimes (especially after restarting the computer I'm working on, or after updating some packages), when I <kbd>Run</kbd> the code (via a React Native configuration for Android in IntelliJ), I'm getting errors like:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':linkedin-sdk:packageReleaseResources'.
> Error: Cannot create directory E:\<appname>\android\linkedin-sdk\build\intermediates\
                                    incremental\packageReleaseResources\merged.dir\values
```

What I'm currently doing is manually deleting several of these build folders (e.g. `<appname>\android\build`, `<appname>\android\app\build`, `<appname>\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build` etc.) whenever this happens - which works, but is quite tedious and annoying.

I am not too familiar with gradle, so I don't know if [relevant gradle `clean` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34027482/3372061) apply here. I don't remember encountering problems like this when working on native projects in Android Studio, so I'm concluding this is something specific to RN-for-android builds.

If this information is useful, I'm using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'`, IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1, Win 10. I'm not running IntelliJ as admin.

Would anybody please suggest a way to automate this deletion? I'd also love to know what causes this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a batch script in the root path of my project, with the following contents:

#### `clean.bat`:

```sh
rmdir /S /Q %~dp0android\build
rmdir /S /Q %~dp0android\app\build
rmdir /S /Q %~dp0android\linkedin-sdk\build
rmdir /S /Q %~dp0node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build
rmdir /S /Q %~dp0node_modules\react-native-linkedin-sdk\android\build
```

And added a run configuration that executes it using the [Batch Scripts Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/265-batch-scripts-support) plugin (though it can also be done manually).

It doesn't solve the root problem, but at least saves some time when deleting these offending folders.