# Android Studio projects taking up too much space

Tags: android-studio, hard-drive

my android studio project is taking up too much space . I only have 100 gig hard drive. is there any way i can clear up some space?

Comment: upgrading your physical memory ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you can upgrade and add another hard drive or delete some not-used projects. Or you can delete old SDK that you don't really use.

Look.. there is a lot of ways to empty your disk and you can find most of them on the internet but this place is just not right for this kind question.

http://www.howtogeek.com/125923/7-ways-to-free-up-hard-disk-space-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Delete All files inside directory ~YourApplication\app\build... Whenever you open this project in Android studio, it will regenerate these files again. It will reduce your project space when your are not using it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you were looking for (in project in Andriod Studio)

```
Build > Clean Project
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio)