# Using custom fonts crashes my application

Tags: android, custom-font

I am using Custom font in my application using typeface class. when I run my application it crashes and open the .otf file in a tab. Images are linked.
Thanx in advance :-)

here is my java code:

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                //params.setMargins(100,100,500,100);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"/fonts/AdobeArabic-Regular.otf");
                text.setTypeface(tf);
                text.setPadding(150,100,150,100);
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
                //text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);

                text.setLayoutParams(params);
```

[Here is my error window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrgG5.png)

Comment: where are you putting the assets folder ?!! under which directory?!!

Comment: open the Here in my error window! which i linked. It shows the proper foldering.

Comment: did you try to clean it ?!!

Comment: how can i clean it ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanx for Your help ! but the issue is not that you r pointing. opening file location of my (.ttf) is set as a txt file... thats creating a problem !

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below one.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AdobeArabic-Regular.otf");
```

You just added extra `'/'` in front of fonts.

Comment: with or without using / . the output is same

Comment: With / my application going crash. My application only works without /. Did you added your text view with any layout or in your main view?

Comment: Thanx for sharing.  but the issue is not that you r pointing. i was opening (.ttf) as a txt file... thats creating a problem ..