# Android project building error - Symbol file with package cannot be empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I have cloned an android project from gitlab. After building the project it shows the below error with build failed.

> java.io.IOException: Internal error: Symbol file with package cannot be empty.

[image]

The project is okay on the other android studio from where it pushed to gitlab. what should I do to prevent this error. thanks in advance.

Comment: post a screenshot

Comment: screenshot added. please have a look.

Comment: Please try to make a [`Gradle clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581254/4385913) and then press `Run` again

Comment: sorry. `Build > Clean Project` got the same error.

Comment: @NishikantoSarkarSimul have you found any solution ?

Comment: The solution was weird. I closed the project and removed the shortcut app link from android studio startup window and also did update the studio and it fixed my error.

Comment: @Nishikanto have you got the solution? If you got the solution can you share it? I'm facing the same problem. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @SouravRoy Yes. The solution was weird. I closed the project from the file menu and removed the shortcut app link from android studio startup window and open the project again, also did update the studio and it fixed my error. :)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked for me… also invalidated catche and restarted… but no luck…

Comment: you can try by update your android studio and related build script of your project with the latest versions. I think the problem is with the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me was to change the Gradle version from **project structure**.
in my case, I changed the version to match the local Gradle distribution I downloaded before and then going into Gradle setting in the project settings to check the use local Gradle distribution option of the same version.