# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1

Tags: android, dependencies, android-volley

I tried to import android volley into my project, but it failed. I dont know what happened. This is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.wifi1"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And this is the build.gradle for project:

```
 buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried using volley library version 1.1.1, 1.1.0, the one from mcxiaoke, and a few other versions, but none of them worked. I also tried to switch my gradle version, and also tried to create local library using android volley that I cloned. Someone suggested to add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to allproject repositories, I also tried it, but it also didnt work. Of course I have also tried to disable offline gradle from Settings menu, but it didnt change anything.

this is the error :

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
```

Everytime I changed the volley version the error was just like that too.
I dont know what to do now, please help

PS: if i comment/remove the volley dependency my project works 100% fine, and  I dont use a proxy-protected internet

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com" 
     }
 }}
```

To your `build.gradle` and then make a [Clean project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581254/4385913) also Invalidate Cache & Restart from file options should work.

Comment: Still doesnt work.

Turns out, it cant compile any remote library when i tried with another library.

Got any clue about this?

Comment: still havng the same problem?

Comment: Did you get the solution?