# com.example.lun.pocket_health_advisor:attr/colorError)' not found

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build this https://github.com/WLun001/pocket-health-advisor

But I'm getting the following error.

What can I do?

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception:
>   Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\Jarup.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\card-form-3.5.0.aar\cb262b69320916545281c54ceaa4ba26\res\values\values.xml:57:5-60:13:
>   AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorError (aka
>   com.example.lun.pocket_health_advisor:attr/colorError)' not found.
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception:
>   Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\Jarup\AndroidStudioProjects\healthcare\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2493:
>   error: style attribute 'attr/colorError (aka
>   com.example.lun.pocket_health_advisor:attr/colorError)' not found.
>   error: failed linking references.

Comment: `colorError` either needs to be defined or removed. search the project for that string. this "question" does not even feature any question, nor a single `?` question mark. using pastebin might be just as useful.

Comment: it is showing me error and not posting it @cricket_007

Comment: yes @MartinZeitler please solve it.it would be very helpful for me

Comment: At the very least, please say you didn't edit any of that source code? And why do you think you need to use this specific app, if it isn't yours and the owner doesn't seem interested in even fixing it themselves? ... Even if we can build it, the problem could be only your machine

Comment: I had choose this project to submit  this project in myclg

Comment: @premkumar use `Edit` > `Find` > `Find in Path ...` and enter `colorError` there. you can't just use a color, which had never been defined, else you get an error message alike the one you've posted. it might be referenced in `values/values.xml` or `values/styles.xml`.

Comment: it might be this one issue: https://github.com/WLun001/pocket-health-advisor/issues/6 ...while `errorColor` does not exist in the whole project: https://github.com/WLun001/pocket-health-advisor/search?q=colorError&unscoped_q=colorError ...which makes me believe, you were messing around and were introducing it; it's author is not to blame. just click "revert changes" in Git client - or check out a fresh copy, problem solved.

Comment: What you mean by fresh copy ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be from your libraries. To solve this problem, you can use other versions of the added libraries

Long ago, this happened to me for this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Or you can use the following links

[how to project clean in the android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio)

Comment: What part of the error says it's a library problem? The package in the error is `com.example`, so that's certainly not a problem with AppCompat